# Laravel 5 AngularJS CORS issue

Tags: laravel, authentication, cors

Folks i am new to Laravel and trying to do Authentication from AngularJS for which i need to set-up CORS in Laravel 5.

Tried setting-up CORS middleware.
Tried setting-up: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors
Tried putting CORS headers in index.php

None of the above solutions works for me please if someone can just guide me a little.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you get CORS exception error in browser, it may because of another exception. with laravel-cors package if your application excepted any exception, CORS exception throwed.
Check your `laravel.log` file for more details